# Angular 2 and one-way binding from the client to the backend

Tags: angular, typescript, binding

If I use the brackets, the binding goes from the backend to the client like this.

```
<div>
  <span>Name</span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Konrad" [value]="name">
</div>
```

I want the exact opposite, either one-way to the back or, at least, two-way bound. I've tried both of the following but neither conveys the changes from the front to the private field in the back.

```
<div>
  <span>Name</span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Konrad" (change)="name">
</div>

<div>
  <span>Name</span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Konrad" [(change)]="name">
</div>
```

What am I missing?

The aim is to let the input box be empty (hence showing the value of the placeholder) and as soon as the user types in something, have access to the value in the back.

I suppose that I could use the tagification and refer to the component by `@viewChild`. I also could fire an event on `(change)=updateName($event)` but both seems to me like somewhat hacky and not the best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[(change)]`

```
<div>
  <span>Name</span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Konrad" [(ngModel)]="name">
</div>
```

This provide a two-way binding. Which means the input field will show the value of `name`, but at the same time update `name` when user type in the field.

Initialize `name='';` in the component, and you will have your desire effect.

If you need to trigger function `nameChanged()`, add `ngModelChange`

```
<div>
  <span>Name</span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Konrad" [(ngModel)]="name" (ngModelChange)="nameChange()">
</div>
```

Ref: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#event-binding (Search for ngModel)

Comment: Oh, so `ngModel` is in fact a specific thing? I thought it was just a generic variable or event name. Now I feel stupid... Where is that declared? I've looked all over my code and there's nothing like that. Is it a reserved word or something?

Comment: @KonradViltersten yes, `ngModel` and `ngModelChange` are both reserved words.

Comment: Not quite yet. I'm trying out different things at the moment before I get back to you with a follow up (out of respect to your help, of course). I'm getting the message *Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. "
</div>* and I do have declared the back-field `testOnly="qqq"` and tried also with `testOnly: string = "www"` etc. Totally lost.

Comment: Got it. I had to add `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
` **and** `imports: [...FormsModule]`. It works now!